Realizar interacciones sobre un objeto generado
Para generar objetos usando amcharts utilizo la función  am4core.create("mapchart", am4maps.MapChart) posterior asigno un archivo json a la variante geodataSource.url entonces se puede visualizar el mapa, entonces necesito saber como se adjunta, es decir es posible interactuar usando el puntor y la rueda del mouse para hacer zoom.
Lo siguiente es hacer interacciones de eventos de entrada o click sobre alguna posición especifica del mapa, para esto usar una función eventoClick y dirigir el enfoque a una coordenada especifica del objeto svg generado.
por ejemplo para responder a las interacciones sobre el objeto svg especifico el id que asigno en la etiqueta <svg ... id = "objetoMapa">
document.getElementById("objetoMapa").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert('Map was clicked!');
});`

ahora es posible asignar a una variable de tipo objeto document.getElementById("objetoMapa") y al reaccionar el evento de click usar los datos correspondientes para document.getElementById("objetoMapa").x, document.getElementById("objetoMapa").y esto para la parte de datos o variables de objetos subconjuntos. La interacción al momento de seleccionar una región es que esta se incremente en zoom y tenga el efecto de posicionarse a la coordenada especifica enfocándose en el estado seleccionado.

Entiendo que el objeto svg esta colocado en la etiqueta div entonces quizas no este relacionado con el canvas al interactuar con eventos de el usuario.
